# How can I start an Express app using Now?

Tags: node.js, vercel

When deploying to Now, I'm trying to build and start an Express server. It's currently building, but not starting the server.

My package.json looks like this, am I missing anything?

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "export": "next build && next export"
  }
```

Comment: Which version of now? v1 or 2?

Comment: I'm not specifying, so I'm going to assume it's defaulting to v2!

Comment: You should specify in `now.json` version: 1 or 2. You can now tackle the problem appropriately

Comment: How does that help with the problem though?

Comment: They have a different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have a file called `/utilities/app.ts` where I setup my common express configuration (this is what I use but you can add/remove things as needed):

```
import express from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import { commonMiddlewares } from '../middlewares'
const expressApp = express();
expressApp.use(helmet());
expressApp.set("trust proxy", 1);
expressApp.use(...commonMiddlewares);
export const app = expressApp;
```

Then in the api endpoint where I want to use express I import this utility:

```
import { app } from "../utilities/app";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
app.get("*", async (req: Request, res: Response) => { ... })
```